# EXCEL - Days between last appearance using name & date

Tags: excel, date

I would like to find the days between the last appearance using Match I think for the name and find the difference between the current date and the last date they appeared. I would like to customize it though.If they appeared on 10/12 and again on 10/13 I would like a 0. Because there were no days off. But for 10/12 and again on 10/14 it would be a 1. I would like it up to 6 days, anything past that I would like it to be 6.

`C2=IFERROR(DAYS($B2,INDIRECT("A"&MAX(IF(A2=$A$1,ROW($A$1),0)))),0)`

**DATA:**

```
Team  Date
BOS   1980-10-10
BUF   1980-10-10
CGY   1980-10-10
CHI   1980-10-10
HFD   1980-10-10
NYR   1980-10-10
DET   1980-10-11
EDM   1980-10-11
BOS   1980-10-12
CGY   1980-10-12
CHI   1980-10-12
CLR   1980-10-12
DET   1980-10-12
HFD   1980-10-12
LAK   1980-10-12
LAK   1980-10-12
MNS   1980-10-12
MTL   1980-10-12
NYI   1980-10-12
NYR   1980-10-12
BOS   1980-10-13
BUF   1980-10-13
CGY   1980-10-13
CHI   1980-10-13
CLR   1980-10-13
EDM   1980-10-13
HFD   1980-10-13
MTL   1980-10-13
NYI   1980-10-13
NYR   1980-10-13
```

**RESULT**

```
Team    Date    Days Rest
BOS 1980-10-10  6
BUF 1980-10-10  6
CGY 1980-10-10  6
CHI 1980-10-10  6
HFD 1980-10-10  6
NYR 1980-10-10  6
DET 1980-10-11  6
EDM 1980-10-11  6
BOS 1980-10-12  1
CGY 1980-10-12  1
CHI 1980-10-12  1
CLR 1980-10-12  6
DET 1980-10-12  0
HFD 1980-10-12  1
LAK 1980-10-12  6
LAK 1980-10-12  0
MNS 1980-10-12  6
MTL 1980-10-12  6
NYI 1980-10-12  6
NYR 1980-10-12  1
BOS 1980-10-13  0
BUF 1980-10-13  2
CGY 1980-10-13  0
CHI 1980-10-13  0
CLR 1980-10-13  0
EDM 1980-10-13  1
HFD 1980-10-13  0
MTL 1980-10-13  0
NYI 1980-10-13  0
NYR 1980-10-13  0
```

Comment: i don't understand. BOS appears on 10-10, 10-12 and 10-13, but the days rest is 6, 1 and 2?

Comment: That should have been 0, sorry

Comment: This question doesn't make much sense as-is.  Why are the same ones listed repeatedly, some more than once on the same day?  Please show your attempt at a solution and explain where you're having a issue.

Comment: must have been two games in the same day. Im sorry your having a hard time understanding it. Its pretty straight forward. Theres a name and a date. By date check to see if the name appears before the current date if so subtract the dates. If the other portion is not possible than I can adjust that my self. Just looking for a formula to take the two dates and subtract.

Comment: Formula updated

Answer (score 1):

**Edit:**  After posting I realised I'm getting very different results from you.  Your first records are returning 6 as they're comparing to todays date - very much past the 6 day limit.
My formula is comparing the current Team date against the previous Team date and doesn't take into account the next, as yet unplayed, game.
I'll leave the answer up as it may be useful.

On each row you need to perform a `MATCH` on the Teams below the current one.

To get a reference to the rest of the Team data below the current row you can use `INDEX` and `COUNTA`.
Entered on row 2 the formula below will reference cells `A3:A31`, dragged down to row 3 it will reference `A4:A31` and so on.  Used on its own it will return a `#VALUE` error in most cases.

```
=$A3:INDEX($A:$A,COUNTA($A:$A))
```

Combined with the `MATCH` function it will return how many rows down the next occurrence of the Team is, or an `#N/A` error.

```
=MATCH($A2,$A3:INDEX($A:$A,COUNTA($A:$A)),0)
```

Add the current row number to the result to give the actual row the next occurrence is on:

```
=MATCH($A2,$A3:INDEX($A:$A,COUNTA($A:$A)),0)+ROW()
```

Next the date in column B of the returned row number needs to be referenced.  `INDEX` can be used to reference all of column B and return the value from the correct row:

```
=INDEX($B:$B,MATCH($A2,$A3:INDEX($A:$A,COUNTA($A:$A)),0)+ROW())
```

This can then be compared with the date on the current row to find the difference (and minus 1 so the next day = 0):

```
=DATEDIF($B2,INDEX($B:$B,MATCH($A2,$A3:INDEX($A:$A,COUNTA($A:$A)),0)+ROW()),"d")-1
```

Deal with any errors (`#N/A` if last mention of Team and `#NUM!` if last item in list):

```
=IFERROR(DATEDIF($B2,INDEX($B:$B,MATCH($A2,$A3:INDEX($A:$A,COUNTA($A:$A)),0)+ROW()),"d")-1,"-")
```

Now there's just the -1 to deal with for *LAK* on row 16.  The shortest way I can think of is to use the next column for your final result:

```
=IF($C2<0,0,$C2)
```